# Synchronized method calls itself recursively. Is this broken?

Tags: java, recursion, synchronized

The point of this question is to illustrate that Java is not working as I expected.

How would you expect the following code to behave?

```
public class SynchTester {
  private static SynchTester synchTester;

  public synchronized static SynchTester getSynchTester(){
    if(synchTester==null){
      synchTester = new SynchTester();
    }

    return synchTester;
  }

  private SynchTester() {
    SynchTester myTester = getSynchTester();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SynchTester tester = SynchTester.getSynchTester();
  }
}
```

I would expect it to hang with a deadlock waiting on the recursion to complete, but instead it throws StackOverflow. Evidently synchronized does not block access to the same thread.

Is this a bug?

Comment: I might be missing something, but I can't see the synchronized keyword in your code.

Comment: @Disco3 sorry, sloppy of me. Changed the source.

Comment: Synchronized locks are reentrant.

Comment: @DuncanJones cite your source, please.

Comment: @Thom See my complete answer below.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

In Java, synchronized locks are [reentrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29).

> Recall that a thread cannot acquire a lock owned by another thread. **But a thread can acquire a lock that it already owns**. Allowing a thread to acquire the same lock more than once enables reentrant synchronization. This describes a situation where synchronized code, directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock. Without reentrant synchronization, synchronized code would have to take many additional precautions to avoid having a thread cause itself to block.

*Source: see bottom of [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)*

Comment: The later scenario discussed here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/286374/can-multiple-synchronized-methods-in-same-object-run-concurrently

Answer (score 3):

A synchronized method needs to be able to get a lock on the monitor object. The monitor object is the instance (or class for a static method). A thread that already has the lock does not need to get it again. So yes, that could cause a stackoverflow (harhar).

Comment: That's kinda what I was thinking. Cite your source, please?

Comment: @Thom Personal experience, mostly, but also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Answer (score 3):

from the [java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html):

> When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.

So I think the syncronized keyword worked as expected, and a synchronized recursive call is perfectly legal (and working) in java.